# SHA-1 Digest Reduction

Tags: digest, reduction, sha1

I'm using QR Code barcodes to store UUIDs in my system and I need to check that the barcodes generated are mine and not someone else's. I also need to keep the encoded data short so that the QR Codes remain in the lower version range and remain easy to scan.

My approach is to take the UUID raw value number (a 128-bit value) and a 16 bit checksum and then Base64 encoded that data before converting to a QR code. So far so good, this works perfectly.

To generate the checksum I take the string version of the UUID and combine it with a long secret string and XOR the odd bytes together to produce a SHA-1 hash.  But this hash is too long, so I XOR all the old bytes together to produce half the checksum, and likewise with the even bytes to produce the other half.

What worries me is that I have compromised the SHA-1 system needlessly by XORing it down.  Would it be better to just take two unmanipulated bytes from somewhere within the result?   I accept that a 16-bit checksum won't be as secure as a 160-bit checksum, but that is a price I have to pay for usability with the barcodes.  What I really don't want to find is that I've now provided a checksum that is easy to crack as the UUID is transmitted in the clear.

If there is a better way of generating the checksum that would also be a suitable answer to the question.  As always many thanks for your time or just reading this, double plus good thanks if you post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no reason to do any XORing. Simply taking the first two bytes will be as (in)secure.

To keep the code version as small as possible, you might want to convert the 144 bit value to a decimal string and encode that. QR Codes have different characters sets and encode numbers efficiently. Base64 can only be encoded as 8 bit values in QR codes so you add 30% right there.

Comment: Thanks smparkes, especially the tip about converting to a decimal string.